# regexp_replace function in HIVE

Tags: hive, regexp-replace

How using the regexp_replace function in HIVE can I cut the markup from this string:

```
Abc abc ","<a href="http://,557244.html" id=" ">abc abc abc .</a>
```

I want to get: Abc abc abc abc abc
Does anyone know?

Comment: Abc abc ","<a href="http://,557244.html" id=" ">abc abc abc .</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column WTF contains

> Abc abc ","<a href="http://,557244.html" id=" ">abc abc abc .</a>

then `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(WTF,'<[^>]*>',''), '[",.]','')` removes all XML markup stuff, then punctuation, to return

> Abc abc abc abc abc

That's plain old regular expression syntax, nothing specific to Hive.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have one more question.
How in this sentence: "abc abc &@! aaa bbb ccc" remove everything after "&@!" - to get in the end: abc abc

Comment: Replace `&@!.*$` with empty string.

Comment: BTW, you may tag the answer as "accepted" if it's a good answer ;-)